# how to compare the actual field value against a given parameter in a where caluse in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

The situation is, we are using our own encryption. Now I was tasked to do a search module whereby I need to pull out the data. The thing, is our datas are encrypted.
so let's say I have a parameter = 'abcde12345', then the value of the column is like 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf1234asdfasdfasdf'. How am I supposed to compare my parameter against the column's actual data using the where clause in the active record ?.
by default, the codeigniter 3 "where" clause works like this

```
$this->db->where('the_column', $myparameter);
```

So I tried

```
$this->db->where($object->ourDecryptor('the_column'), $myparameter);
```

That thing above didn't work.

or this

```
$this->db->where('the_column', $object->ourEncryptor($myparameter));
```

this will definitely not work because, whenever you encrypt, it's a different hash already.
So how ?

Comment: Encrypt the parameter & compare it to the column

Comment: it will not work, why?, because whenever we encrypt, there's always a new hash. it won't match the one in database

Comment: So no one can ever read the encrypted data in your database? Including you?

Comment: Without explaining what "the column" encryption is & what or why you're trying to match it with $parameter you cannot get much help. When encrypting things you're expected to be able to verify that unencrypted data if encrypted you can get a matching value

Comment: Anyway.. I've solved my problem,What I did was, "if" the parameter is set and not empty, then I pulled out "all" the data selecting only that particular column, and then..I looped through the data and decrypt and compare it with the paramater....issue solved :)